# sql use distinct while inserting other columns into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I basically have a lot of duplicate fields in my table and this code below helps solve that

```
select  distinct city,state into dbo.zips from zipcodes
```

a basically looks at all the rows inside zipcodes that have duplicate **city,state** and makes them unique while inserting them into a new table **dbo.zips** . My question is how can I also insert all the other fields from the table zipcodes so that it can also go to the new dbo.zips table. I just want distinct city,state which I can already do but also carry over all other fields I tried to do this

```
select *  distinct city,state into dbo.zips from zipcodes
```

but it did not work

Comment: You can accomplish this using CTE (Common Table Expressions). http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It seems very dangerous to call the resulting table `zips`, when it only contains some of them.  A name like `citystates` seems more appropriate.

Comment: you will need to do an assumption e.g. min, max, avg  for the columns that are not duplicated (alongside city and state) but which you still want in the result set. Could you please post all the columns in zipcodes and which ones you want in zips?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a join back onto the same table:

```
select distinct z.city, z.state, z1.field1, z1.field2 ... z1.fieldn
into dbo.zips
from zipcodes z
inner join zipcodes z1 on z1.city=z.city and z1.state=z.state
```

Comment: This will not remove duplicates but it will greatly increase the number of rows, particularly for a city like New York that has hundreds of zip codes.

Comment: It depends on the fields that he wants to pull from the table. The 'distinct' keyword is still there so would only return unique rows. If he was pulling the zipcode from the joined table, then yes it would return many rows.

Answer (score 0):

But if city, state is duplicate then which of the other columns
They may not be duplicate
Many cities have more than one zip code.
I don't understand why you would only want one zip code from a city in a table name zips

```
select city, state, min(zip)  
  from zipcodes 
 group by city, state
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `row_number()`:

```
select zc.* into dbo.zips
from (select zc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by city, state order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from zipcodes
     ) zc
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you don't want seqnum in the final table, explicitly list the columns that you do want.